# Simplification of this XAML code possible? (MultiDataTrigger, DependencyProperty)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, triggers

finally I got my custom button almost act like I want it to act.
The problem is the code :D (`IsChecked` is a `DependencyProperty`)

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <!-- EventTriggers for LMBUp/LMBDown/MouseEnter/MouseLeave -->
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseEnter}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseLeave}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </MultiDataTrigger>                
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter TargetName="LayoutRoot" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter TargetName="LayoutRoot" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

I think it is a bit "dirty" and it doesn't fully act like expected.
Everytime the user clicks on the button `IsChecked` gets switched from `true` to `false` or vice versa.
Now if the following happens

- IsChecked == true
- User clicks to switch IsChecked to false
- All the time the mouse is ON the button

then I would expect that the button becomes $MouseOverColor$ instead of $ButtonNormalBackground$ because of the first `MultiDataTrigger`.

My questions are if it is possible to simplify the code and to correct the last problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have 'value resolution strategy' issue. `DependencyProperty` has a set strategy of how to resolve the value, [see here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html).

If your animations set the value of `Background` of `LayoutRoot` then other setters will not have affect until you stop the animation (in this case the setters are treated as "Local Value").

You can use `<StopStoryboard>` element in `EnterActions` of second and third triggers. Note that this will write a warning in the output window if the storyboard is already stopped when the trigger was activated.

--Alternatively--

You can use `FillBehavior="Stop"` in your storyboard.